# How to limit a user input minimum value to stream size less one bit?

Tags: c++

I want to limit the minimum value the user can enter to the max stream size minus the higher order bit in order to prevent overflow.  This would be easy if I hard coded the bit sizes allowed but I'd like to utilize the users system and make it more dynamic.  So, how can I subtract the highest bit from the max stream length?

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Get a decimal number from user and validate number entered
while((cout << "Enter decimal number: ") && !(cin >> number)){
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   cout << "Invalid input. Try again\n";
}
```

I think I need to add another test for the min value like this:

```
while((cout << endl << "Enter decimal number: ") && !(cin >> number) && !(number >= -numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())){
```

But somehow subtract the highest order bit from `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`

In my case that would be 31st bit but may be different for someone on a different machine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Becaue you have a loop and cin in loop, you can increase your limit size in loop.

Comment: `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` probably isn't even what you're looking for with respect to limiting the size of a number. Streamsize here is being used to clear out the input buffer. You'll want something more like `numeric_limits<decltype(number)>::max()`, instead, which will give the highest representable value for number.

Comment: Mohsen - Sorry, but I'm not sure how increasing the limit size helps me.  I'm trying to reduce the limit size allowed.  Also, the only loop is if the user enters an invalid number or character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear the highest order bit of any integral type, you can use a function like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
T clearHighestBit(T val) {
    typedef typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type uT;
    uT unsignedVal = val;
    if(!val)
        return 0;
    uT pos = 1;
    while(unsignedVal >>= 1)
        pos <<= 1;
    return val & ~pos;
}
```

All this does is find the highest order bit, creates an unsigned version of T and not-ands it with the original number (that is, it accepts all bits that aren't the highest)

Hope that helps,

Cheers!